# Grails using hibernate basic types

Tags: grails

I have a small grails service that I created, and I am trying to use the type:'text' on a member of a model.  I always see this field come up as a varchar(255) however, even though I have dropped the database and had it recreated.

I essentially have:

```
class eventParameter{
    static belongsTo = [logEvent:LogEvent]
    String name
    String value

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
        value blank:false
    }
    static mapping = {
        value type:'text'
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this does not create the right type of column?

Answer (score 0):

To override the underlying database type, use the `sqlType` mapping.  For example:

```
static mapping = {
    value sqlType:'text'
}
```

Also, check out the relevant section of the Grails Manual: [5.5.2.10 Custom Hibernate Types](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes)

Comment: This should work like you say, and I had tried it as well before posting.  I tried again, and I still end up with varchar(255) instead of text for the column.

Comment: What database are you using?  What does the generated `target/ddl.sql` look like when you run `grails schemaExport`?